# Stored Procedure Problem

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a problem with accessing output in the stored procedure below

```
        DbParameter DbParm = command.CreateParameter();
        DbParm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        DbParm.ParameterName = "@SomeValue";
        DbParm.DbType = DbType.Int32;
        DbParm.Value = null;
        command.Parameters.Add(DbParm);
```

After executing the procedure

```
        command.Parameters["@SomeValue"].Value;
```

Well it always returns Null,I can access to the second second select though.Here is the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SomeThing
  @SomeValue int OUTPUT,
AS

  SELECT @SomeValue=ID  
    FROM SomeTable
   WHERE ID=10;

  SELECT * 
    FROM SomeTable;

GO
```

Comment: Could you show us more of your C# code?  How do you add the parameter to the `command.Parameters` collection?

Comment: Might be a typo so I won't post this as an answer, but the C# code has a type of int32 and the DB code has a type of nvarchar.

Comment: I am suspecting it is beacuse of using 2 selects..

Comment: What is the result of `select * from SomeTable where id = 10` ?

Comment: @Andomar 5 columns id is not null of course

Comment: Well it works without the second select

Comment: I think you may need to revisit the simplification of the SQL queries here: `SELECT @SomeValue = ID FROM SomeTable WHERE ID = 10` -- this simplifies to `SET @SomeValue = 10`, which I don't think was intended.

Comment: Regardless of the queries, have you tried reversing the order of the statements in the sproc? (I'm assuming the second does not depend on the result of the first.)

Comment: @reveresed it  not working again

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: I think I see the problem now.  SQL Server does not assign output parameters until the procedure has finished. While the second select is streaming, the output parameter will not be returned to the client.

Now I'm assuming you're calling `ExecuteNonQuery`, which does not ask for a result set.  SQL Server will halt the procedure at the start of the second select.

If you change your C# code to use `ExecuteReader()`, you can retrieve the output parameter after the reader is done:

```
using (var read = yourCommand.ExecuteReader())
    while (read.Read());
// You should be able to access the output parameter here
```

If you add more streaming selects to the procedure:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable where id = 1;
SELECT 'hello world';
SELECT * FROM SomeTable where null in (1,2,3);
```

You have to get them all out of the way with `NextResult`:

```
using (var read = yourCommand.ExecuteReader()) {
    do {
         while (read.Read());
    } while (read.NextResult());
}
```

before the output parameter will be assigned.  The reason for this is that the value of the output parameter can depend on the last select.  So SQL Server doesn't know the right value before it finishes executing the entire stored procedure.

Comment: well actually it is int I typed it wrong while  simplifing the procedure

Comment: +1 Adding that do/while works perfectly. What's *really* strange is that without it, the first time I got my code working, it *did* return the output value (without the do/while), but then every time after that, I kept getting null.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used dbparameter objects, only system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter objects to accomplish passing parameters to a stored procedure on SQL server.  Try SqlParameter instead.

Comment: It is provider agnostic that's why I was using DbParameter and it is not the problem actually because it is working without the second select